# How to get User's Information in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to get User's IP, User's window ID and User's Server Access time

I can get User's IP with below code but Other things can't get....

getting User's IP code is

**ip <- session$request$REMOTE_ADDR**   at server.R

How to get User's window ID and User's Server Access time ????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long-story-short, there is a limit to what "you" (the app and therefore you, the dev) can know about the connection. I've put in similar requests for some more with RStudio professional support, and what I have below is the current capability. I hope (with no advertised timeline) that more will eventually be available.

I have RStudio Connect, which is technically a different product but similar underlying methods and I believe a lot of shared code.

Here's a shiny app that helps you "discover" things from `session`. I filter out most of the `environment`-like variables in `session` that are either packed full of functions or just not something useful. It's possible I've filtered out too much, you might want to play with it to see if there is more.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  h3("Parsed query string"),
  verbatimTextOutput("queryText"),
  h3("URL components"),
  verbatimTextOutput("sessionText"),
  h3("EnvVars"),
  verbatimTextOutput("envvarText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Parse the GET query string
  output$queryText <- renderText({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    # Return a string with key-value pairs
    paste(names(query), query, sep = "=", collapse=", ")
  })
  # Return the components of the URL in a string:
  output$sessionText <- renderText({
    cls <- sapply(session, function(a) class(a)[1])
    nms <- names(cls[ cls %in% c("list", "character", "numeric", "integer",
                                 "NULL", "logical", "environment", "reactivevalues" ) ])
    nms <- setdiff(nms, ".__enclos_env__")
    paste(
      capture.output(
        str(
          sapply(nms,
                 function(sessnm) {
                   if (inherits(session[[sessnm]], c("environment", "reactivevalues"))) {
                     sapply(names(session[[sessnm]]), function(nm) session[[sessnm]][[nm]], simplify = FALSE)
                   } else if (inherits(session[[sessnm]], c("character", "numeric", "integer"))) {
                     session[[sessnm]]
                   } else class(session[[sessnm]])
                 }, simplify = FALSE),
          nchar.max = 1e5,
          vec.len = 1e5
        )
      ),
      collapse = "\n"
    )
  })
  # Dump the environment variables
  output$envvarText <- renderText({
    paste(
      capture.output(
        str(as.list(Sys.getenv()))
      ),
      collapse = "\n"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's some sample output, cleansed for private information. (Context for this output: I changed the server's IP address to be `111.222.333.444`, otherwise that should be the external IP address. Also, this is behind an nginx reverse proxy for a few reasons, so `REMOTE_ADDR` (for instance) is not very exciting ... but it normally might be for you.)

```
List of 10
 $ groups       : chr [1:45] "Admins" "Analytics" "Synology Desktop"
 $ user         : chr "r2evans"
 $ userData     : Named list()
 $ singletons   : chr(0) 
 $ request      :List of 24
  ..$ HTTP_UPGRADE                 : chr "websocket"
  ..$ HTTP_CONNECTION              : chr "Upgrade"
  ..$ HTTP_GUID                    : chr "_6433vf0"
  ..$ QUERY_STRING                 : chr ""
  ..$ httpuv.version               :Classes 'package_version', 'numeric_version'  hidden list of 1
  .. ..$ : int [1:3] 1 5 2
  ..$ SERVER_NAME                  : chr "127.0.0.1"
  ..$ SCRIPT_NAME                  : chr ""
  ..$ SERVER_PORT                  : chr "40386"
  ..$ REMOTE_PORT                  : chr "52858"
  ..$ HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_VERSION   : chr "13"
  ..$ rook.input                   :Classes 'NullInputStream', 'R6' <NullInputStream>
  Public:
    close: function () 
    read: function (l = -1L) 
    read_lines: function (n = -1L) 
    rewind: function ()  
  ..$ PATH_INFO                    : chr "/websocket/"
  ..$ rook.version                 : chr "1.1-0"
  ..$ rook.errors                  :Classes 'ErrorStream', 'R6' <ErrorStream>
  Public:
    cat: function (..., sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL) 
    flush: function ()  
  ..$ HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR         : chr "111.222.333.444:61928, ::1"
  ..$ HTTP_SHINY_SERVER_CREDENTIALS: chr "{\"user\":\"r2evans\",\"groups\":[\"Admins\",\"Analytics\",\"Synology Desktop\"]}"
  ..$ HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY       : chr "NbavAciNEKYiS1AN/NGlVQ=="
  ..$ HTTP_SHINY_SHARED_SECRET     : chr "65567ccb5db3d2990df150611eb022f4"
  ..$ REMOTE_ADDR                  : chr "127.0.0.1"
  ..$ HEADERS                      : Named chr [1:10] "Upgrade" "_6433vf0" "127.0.0.1:40386" "NbavAciNEKYiS1AN/NGlVQ==" "13" "{\"user\":\"r2evans\",\"groups\":[\"Admins\",\"Analytics\",\"Synology Desktop\"]}" "65567ccb5db3d2990df150611eb022f4" "websocket" "Go-http-client/1.1" "111.222.333.444!:61928, ::1"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "connection" "guid" "host" "sec-websocket-key" "sec-websocket-version" "shiny-server-credentials" "shiny-shared-secret" "upgrade" "user-agent" "x-forwarded-for"
  ..$ rook.url_scheme              : chr "http"
  ..$ REQUEST_METHOD               : chr "GET"
  ..$ HTTP_USER_AGENT              : chr "Go-http-client/1.1"
  ..$ HTTP_HOST                    : chr "127.0.0.1:40386"
 $ closed       : chr "logical"
 $ token        : chr "3a358fb6a0d42c688ea8693b67d448cb"
 $ clientData   :List of 13
  ..$ output_queryText_hidden  : logi FALSE
  ..$ output_sessionText_hidden: logi FALSE
  ..$ output_envvarText_hidden : logi FALSE
  ..$ url_search               : chr ""
  ..$ url_hash_initial         : chr ""
  ..$ singletons               : chr ""
  ..$ url_protocol             : chr "https:"
  ..$ allowDataUriScheme       : logi TRUE
  ..$ url_port                 : chr ""
  ..$ url_hostname             : chr "server.mydomain.com"
  ..$ pixelratio               : int 2
  ..$ url_hash                 : chr ""
  ..$ url_pathname             : chr "/content/23/"
 $ input        : Named list()
 $ progressStack:List of 10
  ..$ .__enclos_env__:<environment: 0x652f8e8> 
  ..$ clone          :function (deep = FALSE)  
  ..$ as_list        :function ()  
  ..$ size           :function ()  
  ..$ peek           :function ()  
  ..$ pop            :function ()  
  ..$ push           :function (..., .list = NULL)  
  ..$ initialize     :function (init = 20L)  
  ..$ private        :<environment: 0x652fbc0> 
  ..$ self           :<environment: 0x652f8e8>
```

And the environment variables:

```
List of 42
 $ EDITOR              : chr "vi"
 $ HOME                : chr "/home"
 $ LANG                : chr "en_US.UTF-8"
 $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH     : chr "/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server"
 $ LN_S                : chr "ln -s"
 $ LOGNAME             : chr "rstudio-connect"
 $ MAKE                : chr "make"
 $ PAGER               : chr "/usr/bin/pager"
 $ PATH                : chr "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/rstudio-connect/ext/pandoc2"
 $ PWD                 : chr "/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app"
 $ R_ARCH              : chr ""
 $ R_BROWSER           : chr "xdg-open"
 $ R_BZIPCMD           : chr "/bin/bzip2"
 $ R_CONFIG_ACTIVE     : chr "rsconnect"
 $ R_DOC_DIR           : chr "/usr/share/R/doc"
 $ R_GZIPCMD           : chr "/bin/gzip -n"
 $ R_HOME              : chr "/usr/lib/R"
 $ R_INCLUDE_DIR       : chr "/usr/share/R/include"
 $ R_LIBS              : chr "/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3:"
 $ R_LIBS_SITE         : chr "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library"
 $ R_LIBS_USER         : chr "~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5"
 $ R_PAPERSIZE         : chr "letter"
 $ R_PAPERSIZE_USER    : chr "letter"
 $ R_PDFVIEWER         : chr "/usr/bin/xdg-open"
 $ R_PLATFORM          : chr "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
 $ R_PRINTCMD          : chr "/usr/bin/lpr"
 $ R_RD4PDF            : chr "times,inconsolata,hyper"
 $ R_SESSION_TMPDIR    : chr "/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/Rtmp3WkNTY"
 $ R_SHARE_DIR         : chr "/usr/share/R/share"
 $ RSTUDIO_PANDOC      : chr "/opt/rstudio-connect/ext/pandoc2"
 $ R_SYSTEM_ABI        : chr "linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?"
 $ R_TEXI2DVICMD       : chr "/usr/bin/texi2dvi"
 $ R_UNZIPCMD          : chr "/usr/bin/unzip"
 $ R_ZIPCMD            : chr "/usr/bin/zip"
 $ SED                 : chr "/bin/sed"
 $ SHINY_PORT          : chr "40386"
 $ SHINY_SERVER_VERSION: chr "1.8.2-10"
 $ SHLVL               : chr "0"
 $ TAR                 : chr "/bin/tar"
 $ TMPDIR              : chr "/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp"
 $ USER                : chr "rstudio-connect"
 $ USERNAME            : chr "rstudio-connect"
```

Ultimately, publish this app, visit it, and see what *you* find one your instance.

---

Not requested, but included for completeness: here's an equivalent `plumber` API hit:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(plumber)
#* @get /clientdata
function(req, res){
  classes <- sapply(req, function(a) head(class(a), n=1))
  classes <- classes[! classes %in% c("ErrorStream", "NullInputStream") ]
  classes <- classes[ ! names(classes) %in% c("args", "httpuv.version") ]
  lapply(setNames(nm=names(classes)), function(nm) req[[nm]])
}
```

With output:

```
{
  "SERVER_NAME": [
    "127.0.0.1"
  ],
  "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR": [
    "111.222.333.555:54590, 127.0.0.1"
  ],
  "HTTP_ACCEPT": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "HTTP_DNT": [
    "1"
  ],
  "SERVER_PORT": [
    "33632"
  ],
  "rook.url_scheme": [
    "http"
  ],
  "REQUEST_METHOD": [
    "GET"
  ],
  "HTTP_X_ARR_LOG_ID": [
    "e5bdaca6-dcd7-4ca0-87d5-0d54927244b5"
  ],
  "rook.version": [
    "1.1-0"
  ],
  "HTTP_X_ARR_SSL": [
    "..., CN=*.mydomain.com"
  ],
  "postBody": [],
  "HTTP_RSTUDIO_CONNECT_CREDENTIALS": [
    "{\"user\":\"r2evans\",\"groups\":[\"Admins\",\"Analytics\",\"Synology Desktop\"]}"
  ],
  "HTTP_USER_AGENT": [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0"
  ],
  "SCRIPT_NAME": [
    ""
  ],
  "cookies": [],
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE": [
    "en-US,en;q=0.5"
  ],
  "HTTP_PLUMBER_SHARED_SECRET": [
    "..."
  ],
  "HTTP_REFERER": [
    "https://server.mydomain.com/content/28/__swagger__/"
  ],
  "REMOTE_PORT": [
    "48684"
  ],
  "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING": [
    "gzip, deflate, br"
  ],
  "HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS": [
    "10"
  ],
  "HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL": [
    "/content/28/clientdata"
  ],
  "HTTP_HOST": [
    "127.0.0.1:33632"
  ],
  "HEADERS": [
    "application/json",
    "gzip, deflate, br",
    "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "1",
    "127.0.0.1:33632",
    "10",
    "...",
    "https://server.mydomain.com/content/28/__swagger__/",
    "https://server.mydomain.com/content/28",
    "{\"user\":\"r2evans\",\"groups\":[\"Admins\",\"Analytics\",\"Synology Desktop\"]}",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",
    "e5bdaca6-dcd7-4ca0-87d5-0d54927244b5",
    "..., CN=*.mydomain.com",
    "111.222.333.555:54590, 127.0.0.1",
    "/content/28/clientdata",
    "https://server.mydomain.com:443/content/28/clientdata"
  ],
  "HTTP_X_RSC_REQUEST": [
    "https://server.mydomain.com:443/content/28/clientdata"
  ],
  "HTTP_RSTUDIO_CONNECT_APP_BASE_URL": [
    "https://server.mydomain.com/content/28"
  ],
  "PATH_INFO": [
    "/clientdata"
  ],
  "QUERY_STRING": [
    ""
  ],
  "REMOTE_ADDR": [
    "127.0.0.1"
  ]
}
```