# Detect if R code is running from RStudio Connect

Tags: r, rstudio-connect

I have some content (written in the R language) deployed to an [RStudio Connect](https://www.rstudio.com/products/connect/)  instance.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```r
if (isTRUE(is_connect)) {
  print("Running on Connect")
} else {
  print("Not running on Connect")
}
```

That is, I'd like to have my code detect whether it is running from RStudio Connect or not, and behave differently depending on its environment.

How can I detect, using R code, whether it is running on RStudio Connect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative that I've been using is the `R_CONFIG_ACTIVE` envvar. From https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/process-management/#using-the-config-package,

> By default, R processes launched by RStudio Connect set `R_CONFIG_ACTIVE` to `rsconnect`.

This this, one might use

```r
if (Sys.getenv("R_CONFIG_ACTIVE") == "rsconnect") {
  print("Running on Connect")
} else {
  print("Not running on Connect")
}
```

It's safe to not use `isTRUE` here, since `Sys.getenv` will always return a string of length 1; if it is unset, it returns `""` (still length 1, just empty). (It's okay to use `isTRUE` if you still prefer.)

If you are curious what else is set within the RSC environment, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62546918/3358272) for a quick app that displays env-vars (among others).

Comment: Thank you, the `R_CONFIG_ACTIVE` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Since v1.8.8 (April 2021) RStudio Connect has defined the `CONNECT_SERVER` environment variable to all content runtimes ([source](https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/news/#rstudio-connect-188)).

You could use the existence of this environment variable to detect if you're running on Connect or not:

```r
is_connect = function() {
  Sys.getenv("CONNECT_SERVER") != ""
}
```

You could then use this in your code as:

```r
if (isTRUE(is_connect())) {
  print("Running on Connect")
} else {
  print("Not running on Connect")
}
```

Of course this solution isn't completely fool-proof: there's nothing to stop me from defining a `CONNECT_SERVER` environment variable on my local machine, but so long as you don't do this you'll be fine...

Comment: Note that per the same NEWS doc, *"This can be disabled with the `Applications.DefaultServerEnv` configuration option."*